# How can I reduce delta time spikes in my game loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, game-development

I'm building a PONG Game using the client/server model. I'm calculating and syncing the game state on the server and then sending it to the client to render.

My question is simple how can I improve my game loop so this condition is called less frequently

```
if (deltaTime > 0.02) {
        //! I'm unhappy how often this is triggered
        // Threshold, e.g., 20ms
        console.log(`High Delta Time Detected: ${deltaTime}`);
    }



beginGameLoop(roomID: string) {
    let lastTime = performance.now();
    let counter = 0;

    if (counter++ == 0) console.log('Game loop started');
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        const currentTime = performance.now();
        const deltaTime = (currentTime - lastTime) / 1000; // Convert to seconds
        lastTime = currentTime;

        if (deltaTime > 0.02) {
            //! I'm unhappy how often this is triggered
            // Threshold, e.g., 20ms
            console.log(`High Delta Time Detected: ${deltaTime}`);
        }

        this.gameService.updateGameState(roomID, deltaTime);
        // If game is over, clear the interval
        // if (this.gameService.isGameOver(roomID)) {
        //  clearInterval(intervalId);
        // }
        this.sendGameState(roomID, this.gameService.getGameState(roomID));
    }, 1000 / 60); // Run the loop at approximately 60 FPS
    this.gameService.setIntervalID(roomID, intervalId);
}
```

I let the server run for a few minutes and I got this console log output
[image]

Comment: You don't get much control over when the browser decides to run your game loop. Your code needs to be tolerant of that. But your best bet is to use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of `setInterval`. Then the browser will execute your loop as often as it can, which should be close to the screens refresh rate, instead of a hardcoded 60fps. And if you are trying to communicate with the server on every frame, that's really not going to scale well. Just too much latency there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, this is my server-side code so I can't use requestAnimationFrame there!

Comment: If you set the interval at 60 times per second.... your code will be called 60 times per second... or perhaps I misunderstand the question....

Comment: @Kokodoko - at 60fps one would assume delta time will always be close to 0.016s. If delta time is exceeded by some margin like 4ms the game will start to lag. I'm just wondering if there is a technique that will come closer to the 16ms mark than setInterval.

Comment: Ok sorry for the confusion. But I think since your node server may also have other activities running on the CPU you may always run into unexpected lags every now and then. It depends on the setup of the server machine. At least, that's my impression.